# how to add image in laravel?

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

I want to know How to add image in laravel.
I also know it can do using html/css. But I want to know how to give image path and where put images in laravel(I suppose public img folder in laravel).
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
<img src="(How to give image path??)" alt="" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: `{{ asset('path_to_image') )}}` the asset helper will point to the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your images in the public folder and then you can access them like this

```
{{ asset('/my-picture.png') }}
```

You can also access them using [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) package for building forms and HTML elements, so your code will look like this:

```
{{ HTML::image('/my-picture.png', 'about the picture') }}
```

Comment: I solved my problem as following: <img src="img/course01.jpg" alt="">

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as following:

```
<img src="img/pictureName.jpg" alt="">
```

img is folder in public.I only give path in image simply.

Thanks all.

Comment: Next time make sure that you've tried all the ways that you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{{url('folder_name/file_name_variable')}}" alt="" style="width:100%;">
{{url('folder_name/file_name_variable')}}<br>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

The `storage_path()` is OS file system path. For example in Windows it will be `C:\project\storage` or *nix `/var/www/project/storage`.

The `<img>` can't read the OS path. They read URL, something like `http://domain/image.png`.

For example to read images inside `storage_path`, add this inside `routes/web.php`.

```
Route::get('storage/{name}', function ($name) {

   $path = storage_path($name);

   $mime = \File::mimeType($path);

   header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

   return readfile($path);

})->where('name', '(.*)');
```

#### Usage

```
<img src="{{ get_image('storage/images/logo.png') }}" />
<img src="{{ get_image('storage/images/other.jpg') }}" />
```